# Есть бот техподдержки на python. Но только на одного админа. Если добавить в группу то сообщения не пересылает. Можно ли как-то пофиксить?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Я пытался добавить второго админа в конфигурации и дублировать все строки под "второго" администратора. К сожалению, безуспешно. В телеграме добавил этого бота в группу, сделал администратором, сообщения тоже не пересылает. Бот написан на aiogram'е.

Comment: Код для слабаков, да?

Comment: Можно побольше информации? Например, код бота?